# Is there a simple texteditor accessible from the menu bar for making fast snippets?

Tags: macos, text-editor, menu-bar

Do you know some solution or some clever way how to link some text editor to menu bar with an icon in the menu bar?

The desired app should look something like this:
http://www.sourcedrop.net/mac

BUT:

- no need for hosting on the Internet
- using of local files
- enabling inline editing
- enabling easy search

Comment: http://www.sourcedrop.net/mac this somehow solves my problem even with some overkill that it is hosted on github gist. I dont know how many previous will be displayed in history....

Comment: Note that if you select some text there will be a action in the services menu to paste into a new note (or into a new Aquamacs buffer or similar for other editors)

Comment: If you have a background in Objective-C you can create a menu bar item that simply opens any of the apps in "Buscar 웃"'s answer

Comment: @Arc676 I think Buscar deleted his answer... Anyway I think about few menubar apps as my free-time-development projects ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**NoteAway**](http://noteaway.com) is a free<sup>*</sup> menu bar oriented notes app that seems ideal for your situation.

[image: Screenshot]

<sup><sup>*</sup> with pro in app purchase</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Give Evernote a try. On the Mac, it includes a menu servlet that is a simple text box, which saves to your Evernote.

You don't need to host anything of course, and there is no need to ever visit the Evernote on the web. Its easy search, inline editing, and all your notes are stored in the Evernote app. Evernote sync's to local Evernote files on your Mac, and if you prefer, it can be local only, though I suspect the menu servlet does not sync with the local only files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about

Stickes.app

Or Notes. App

Or TextEdit.app

all available in your OS X

Once you tell me which one you like we can proceed on making a menulet for it.

Comment: please provide links to this apps.

Comment: @andi These applications are already installed on your system. They are not accessible via a menulet though.

Comment: @patrix you are right, so I added information

Comment: Now you got me curious: How do you turn any of them into a menulet? I assume the process is generic so maybe you can just describe it for one of the applications?

Answer (score 1):

What about [Scribblet](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26195/scribblet)?
It includes Saving, Printing and Favorites.

> “**Scribblet is an elegant note app for OS X.**
>
> **Quick access**: Open Scribblet using a convenient icon on the menu bar, or assign a keyboard shortcut that works anywhere.
>
> **Beautiful design**: Great care was taken with the software's minimalist look, which makes it simple to learn and effortless to use.
>
> **Customisable**: Change lots of settings to fit your exact workflow.
>
> **Power users**: Access almost every feature using just the keyboard.
> **Favourites**: Switch between notes instantly using the drop-down menu
> ”

Answer (score 1):

another option is notefile
http://junecloud.com/software/mac/notefile.html

junecloud sync